# The ability to pass a method parameter as an object's state to be changed

Tags: java, object, methods, parameters, this

I actually have two questions about how to do this correctly. I am fairly new to Java programming, and this makes what I want to do hard to do by myself and by not asking any questions.

My first question, is am I using the "this" term correctly here? I have a constructor with a bunch of different elements, and two of the elements are "attack" and "attackLvl". Will this method correctly update the elements?

```
public void updateAttack(int xp){
    this.attack = xp;
    this.attackLvl = levelFromXP(this.attack);
    updateOverall();
}
```

Second, is more of a broad question on how to achieve a certain result. I could make 20+ different methods like the one above, but I would rather pass a parameter through to the statements like the following example, but I don't know how to do it:

```
public void updateAttack(int xp, String skill){
    this.(skill) = xp;
    this.(skill + "Lvl") = levelFromXP(this.skill);
    updateOverall();
}
```

Comment: You don't have a "constructor" with a bunch of different elements.. you have an _object_ with a bunch of _fields_ here, which you may (we can't see) have set previously in the constructor. What you have _looks_ correct, but we don't know what class this is intended to represent -- so it's hard to tell.

Answer (score 1):

And if you want *multiple skills*, by name:

```
protected Map<String,Integer> skillLevelMap = new TreeMap();

public int getSkillLevel (String skill) {
    Integer level = skillLevelMap.get( skill);
    return (level != null) ?  level : 0;
}
public void setSkillLevel (String skill, int level) {
    skillLevelMap.put( skill, level);
}
```

This avoids having to write 5-20 different getters/setters for different kinds of Skill.

Answer (score 0):

1. Yes, your usage of this is correct, but not required.
2. Is 'skill' a GLOBAL variable? If it is, you don't need to pass it anymore in the methods of that same class. In particular,

   ```
   public void updateAttack(int xp){
     skill = xp; //but compiler error since xp is an int and skill is a String
     skill = "Lvl1" + levelFromXP(skill);
     updateOverall();
   }
   ```

**'this'** is only required if there are ambiguities in naming.

Comment: I don't agree with your statement to use `this` only when ambiguity exists.  Prefixing class instance variables with `this` or `super` can provide additional context to other developers reading the code.

Comment: I always prefix class fields I'm **writing** with 'this.' prefix.  It's extremely clear, and very helpful to avoid non-functional assignment. I don't use other prefixes for eg. setter parameters, just distinguish via the 'this.'.

Answer (score 0):

The code doesn't provide enough information to determine if you are using this correctly.  But in general if `attack` and `attackLvl` are fields on your class you are using it correctly.  For example:

```
public class Player(){
    String attackLvl;
    int attack;

    public void updateAttack(int xp){
       this.attack = xp; //reference fields on this class is proper use
       this.attackLvl = levelFromXP(this.attack);
       updateOverall();
    }
}
```

Comment: 'Hitpoints', 'XP' or 'Level' are obvious attributes of player.. but is 'Attack'?

Comment: @ThomasW I have no clue, I was just trying to add some context by wrapping these fields in a class to prove my point.  The OP does not provide enough context to accurately answer the question so I just tried to provide an example of using this with some class instance variables.

Answer (score 0):

**One**

yes you are using the `this` keyword correctly here. In your case (where the parameter has another name as the member variable) it is not even necessary – but it is recommended to use `this` every time when calling a member variable of your class. So keep on using it as you already do it in your example to keep your code understandable and clean.

**Two**

I guess what you intend to do is some kind of *dynamic* naming of your variables, so you would end up with something like

```
this.attackSkill = xp;
this.attackSkillLvl = levelFromXP(this.attackSkill);
this.defenseSkill = xp;
this.defenseSkillLvl =  levelFromXP(this.defenseSkill);
```

Am I interpreting your *pseudo code* example correctly?

Anyway, as you know it is not possible to name your variables dynamically – only if you use a `Map` (as for example a `HashMap`) where you can assign your values to a *key* as you need them:

```
this.skillMap = new HashMap<String,Integer> ();
this.skillMap.put(skill, levelFromXP(skill);
```

Then your `skill` String would be the key with which you can access the value of the skill:

```
this.skillMap.get("attackSkill") // returns the levelFromXP(attackSkillXP);
```

But it depends on what other "skill" values you like to have in your class and which one you use. If you are sure to use always all 20+ different skills, I would recommend a normal `List` or an `Array`.